# Match path-string to Vue Router params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a path-string like `"/foo/123/bar/456"`, which is **not** the current path.

The Vue Router path is set to match `/foo/:fooid/bar/:barid`

Is there a way to use Vue Router to retrieve the params from the string?

Expected:

```js
let params = this.$router.someFunction("/foo/123/bar/456")
// params = {fooid: 123, barid: 456}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `this.$router.resolve("/foo/123/bar/456")`

Note, that it will only match route if there is one corresponding in your routes. The method will give you the Object with "params" property.

```
const matchedRoute = this.$router.resolve("/foo/123/bar/456")
// what you are looking for is under
// matchedRoute.params = {fooid: 123, barid: 456}
```

Comment: Great! Little edit: it's actually under `matchedRoute.[route/resolved/..].params